# Apache Drill: Failure setting up ZK for client

Tags: apache-drill, apache-zookeeper

I am testing Apache Drill with a two server cluster.

Let's say their external IPs are:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

I first setup Zookeeper to run on both, and when I do the status command I get positive response:

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.8/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: leader
```

The way I have my zoo.cfg to get it working was like this:

Server 1:

```
// other default values omitted
clientPort=2181
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=2.2.2.2:2888:3888
```

Server 2:

```
// other default values omitted
clientPort=2181
server.1=1.1.1.1:2888:3888
server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
```

Next I wanted to get Drill running with this cluster, so I modify the drill-override.conf file for the 2 servers as follows:

Server 1:

```
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "test",
  zk.connect: "1.1.1.1:2181,2.2.2.2:2181"
}
```

Server 2:

```
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "test",
  zk.connect: "2.2.2.2:2181,1.1.1.1:2181"
}
```

I can start a drillbit on both servers, and when I do status I get this response on both servers:

```
drillbit is running.
```

But when I then try to open the console via bin/drill-conf I get this stack trace:

```
Error: Failure in connecting to Drill: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: Failure setting up ZK for client. (state=,code=0)
java.sql.SQLException: Failure in connecting to Drill: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: Failure setting up ZK for client.
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:159)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:64)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69)
        at net.hydromatic.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:126)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
        at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:167)
        at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:213)
        at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1083)
        at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1015)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:36)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:742)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:528)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:596)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:375)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:268)
Caused by: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: Failure setting up ZK for client.
        at org.apache.drill.exec.client.DrillClient.connect(DrillClient.java:208)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:151)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failure to connect to the zookeeper cluster service within the allotted time of 10000 milliseconds.
        at org.apache.drill.exec.coord.zk.ZKClusterCoordinator.start(ZKClusterCoordinator.java:123)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.client.DrillClient.connect(DrillClient.java:206)
        ... 19 more
apache drill 1.7.0
"start your sql engine"
```

Why would drill fail to connect to the ZK cluster, which is running just fine?

All ports are open between these two boxes.

Answer (score 1):

### Pre-Requisites

[Prerequisites](https://drill.apache.org/docs/distributed-mode-prerequisites/) for starting drill in distributed mode:

- (Required) Running Oracle JDK version 7
- (Required) Running a ZooKeeper quorum
- (Recommended) Running a Hadoop cluster
- (Recommended) Using DNS

---

### Configuration

As your server IP address:

- **Server 1** - 1.1.1.1
- **Server 2** - 2.2.2.2

Put same configuration in `zoo.cfg` in both Server 1 and Server 2

```
clientPort=2181
server.1=1.1.1.1:2888:3888
server.2=2.2.2.2:2888:3888
```

Similarly same configuration in `drill-override.conf` for **both the servers**

```
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "test",
  zk.connect: "1.1.1.1:2181,2.2.2.2:2181"
}
```

---

### Starting Drill

Start *drillbit* on **all the cluster nodes** using

```
bin/drillbit.sh start
```

---

### Using Drill

- Web UI:

  Open web UI using any node address. For example:

  > 1.1.1.1:8047
- Via Shell:

  Fire `bin/drill-localhost` command and drill shell will appear.

---

### Verify Installation

From drill shell or UI fire

```
SELECT * FROM sys.drillbits;
```

Drill lists information about the Drillbits that are running

---

### Stopping Drill

Fire command

```
bin/drillbit.sh stop
```

Comment: Trying to put the same cfg for zookeeper in both servers results in failure - the zk nodes fail to find each other. I have tried using external ip, internal ip and hostnames. The only time the two nodes can find eachother is when I put 0.0.0.0 for the server the cfg file is on. I'll get either a SocketTimeoutException or BindException when I try to start the quorum.

Comment: @Trant  Did you try to start drillbit (`bin/drillbit.sh start`)

Comment: Using my original zookeeper config? Yes, I did - that's where I wrote that I can see the status of "drillbit is running." but when I try to open a drill console I get that stack trace about failing to connect to zookeeper cluster.

Comment: are you using `./drill-localhost` to view console

Comment: No I used bin/drill-conf. If I run drill-localhost I get this instead of the stack trace shown in original post: .ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: localhost/127.0.0.1:31010